# Como borrar en cascada en spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hola tengo la entidad post

```
@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String caption;
    private String location;
    private int likes;
    private Date postedDate;
    private String username;
    private Long userImageId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private List<Comment> commentsList;
    public Post() {

    }

}
```

y la entidad usuario

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;
    private String email;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String bio;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Post> post;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Post> likedPost;

    public User() {
    }

}
```

Quiero lograr que cuando se elimine un post se eliminen las dependencias a otras tablas, actualmente cuando intento eliminar un post me aparece en la consola:

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`photosocial`.`user_post`, CONSTRAINT `FK993unwep4cqba09j5py92sm9k` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`))

Que hace referencia a la tabla user_post, cual es la notacion para estos casos?, quiero que se elimine por completo las dependencias a otras tablas

Comment: consideraste bajas lógicas en el sistema?

Comment: Es solo un ejercicio propio que hago para aprender

Comment: Elimino post desde un cliente en angular

Comment: Para eliminar las registros dependientes debes utiliza orphanRemoval ejemplo:  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true) esto te permite eliminar en cascada, lo que no recuerdo es si debes regenerar la base de datos.